# Converting the value of an element into a number

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the value of an element, say, an input into a number so I can add numbers. My current code only adds the number to the end:

```js
var inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(inputValue + 9);
```

```html
<input id="input" value="123">
```

I have tried `Number()` but that results in `NaN`. How can I obtain the number value and add a number to it?

Update: I've solved my own question. Oops. Thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: How did you use `Number`?

Comment: `Number(inputValue + 9)`, `Number(inputValue) + 9` and things like that

Comment: Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Comment: `Number(inputValue) + 9` should have worked. Please provide code demonstrating that not working, or any of the other options show in the answers to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that just by using [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
var inputValue = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  console.log(inputValue + 9);
```

```html
<input id="input" value="123">
```

Comment: Please look at the comments on the question; if you see one that starts with "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link to another question. Navigate to that link and see if the answers there answer this question. If so, please don't answer this one, since it is a duplicate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the clarification will make sure to review other questions first before answering

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputValue = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value) + 9;
console.log(inputValue);
```

```html
<input id="input" value="123">
```

You can use `Number.parseFloat` or `Number.parseInt`.

Comment: Please look at the comments on the question; if you see one that starts with "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link to another question. Navigate to that link and see if the answers there answer this question. If so, please don't answer this one, since it is a duplicate.